# Prove that every component of angular momentum commutes with $f$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, angular-momentum, commutator

> Let $f(  \hat {\vec r} , \hat {\vec p} )$ be the any polynomial in variables $r^2, p^2 $ and
> $(\vec r \cdot \vec p)$. prove that every component of angular momentum commutes with $\hat f$:
> $[\hat L_k , f(  \hat {\vec r} , \hat {\vec p} )] = 0 $.

So maybe it is enough to prove for $[\hat L_z]$ ; I know how to proof commutation with $r^2 $ and  $p^2 $ and $(\vec r \cdot \vec p)$ but how to prove commutation of any combination of those?
I tried proving this using $f = (\vec r + \vec p)^2$ but I don't know if thats enough to proof any polynomial.

Comment: Do you see $[\hat L_k ,    \hat { r ^2}  \hat { p ^2}] =   \hat { r ^2}   [\hat L_k ,   \hat { p ^2}]+ [\hat L_k ,    \hat { r ^2} ]  \hat { p ^2} $, etc?.

Comment: Now I see, thank you so $[\hat L_k , \hat {r^2}\hat {p^2} (\vec r \cdot \vec p)] = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commuting with $L$ is equivalent to being invariant under rotations. The quantities $r^2$, $r\cdot p$ and $p^2$ are all rotationally invariant, as is any function of them. That is all that is needed.